# Why is a -> a not a functor?

Tags: functional-programming, functor, category-theory

Specifically referring to https://bartoszmilewski.com/2015/04/07/natural-transformations/

Author says "This is not a functor".

I can define `fmap :: (a -> b) -> (a -> a) -> (b -> b)` as `fmap f aa = id`, which seems to adhere to the functor laws.

I don't mean why it's not explicitly part of the Functor typeclass in X language, I just mean why it wouldn't be acknowledged as a functor.

Comment: That's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I'll clarify my question.

Comment: Notice that the type `a -> a` has just one member, the identity function `id`. It's pretty much equivalent to Unit.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov - None of those function have type `a -> a`.

Comment: @Lee Again, how is it relevant to the question?

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov None of those functions work on all types `a`.

Comment: @Bergi OK, but your second statement is definitely false. `a -> a` is not equivalent to `()`. The first one can be specialized to `Int -> Int`, `String -> String` etc.

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov OK, I probably should have said "with regards to being a functor". Is `()` a `Functor` instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the context of Haskell, I think you're talking about `newtype Endo a = Endo (a -> a)` (using a newtype to get the required `* -> *` kind).

Indeed we could define

```
instance Functor Endo where
    fmap _ _ = Endo id
```

But one of the Functor laws is `fmap id = id`, i.e. fmapping with id has to be the same as doing nothing. Your suggested definition violates this rule:

```
fmap id (Endo toUpper)
```

should result in `Endo toUpper`, but your code makes it `Endo id`. One of those transforms `'a'` to `'A'`, the other turns `'a'` into `'a'`.

Comment: Indeed, `fmap id (+1)` returns `(+0)` rather than `(+1)`. The first law is violated.

Comment: I see, so that's the idea. Totally brainfarted that a -> a would inhabited by non-id functions.