# What kind of morphism is `filter` in category theory?

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, category-theory

In category theory, is the `filter` operation considered a morphism? If yes, what kind of morphism is it? Example (in Scala)

```
val myNums: Seq[Int] = Seq(-1, 3, -4, 2)

myNums.filter(_ > 0)
// Seq[Int] = List(3, 2) // result = subset, same type

myNums.filter(_ > -99)
// Seq[Int] = List(-1, 3, -4, 2) // result = identical than original

myNums.filter(_ > 99)
// Seq[Int] = List() // result = empty, same type
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To answer are question like this, I'd like to first understand what is the *essence* of filtering.

For instance, does it matter that the input is a list? Could you filter a tree? I don't see why not! You'd apply a predicate to each node of the tree and discard the ones that fail the test.

But what would be the shape of the result? Node deletion is not always defined or it's ambiguous. You could return a list. But why a list? Any data structure that supports appending would work. You also need an empty member of your data structure to start the appending process. So any unital magma would do. If you insist on associativity, you get a monoid. Looking back at the definition of `filter`, the result is a list, which is indeed a monoid. So we are on the right track.

So `filter` is just a special case of what's called `Foldable`: a data structure over which you can fold while accumulating the results in a monoid. In particular, you could use the predicate to either output a singleton list, if it's true; or an empty list (identity element), if it's false.

If you want a categorical answer, then a fold is an example of a catamorphism, an example of a morphism in the category of algebras. The (recursive) data structure you're folding over (a list, in the case of `filter`) is an initial algebra for some functor (the list functor, in this case), and your predicate is used to define an algebra for this functor.

Comment: I think this is where divergent generalizations begin. You are looking at the `List` data structure, and generalize it to `Foldable`. However, I don't see why one couldn't apply `filter` to the monad that models random sampling, to generate only those samples that fulfill certain predicate. This would have essentially nothing to do with foldable data structures, but it would fit nicely into the monadic framework for generating complex random objects. I'm not sure that `Foldable` is the only possible "essence" that can be extracted from `filter`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin It would appear as though this monad must contain a foldable. For instance, consider [Supply](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-supply) — it has an operation [`supplies`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-supply-0.3/docs/src/Control-Monad-Supply.html#supplies) that fetches a list. All the Reactive programming is, to my understanding, another case where you generate a list of events in a monad and then deal with it as though it was pure. Does this persuade you to reconsider the statement *"this would have essentially nothing to do with foldable data structures"*?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov The `Supply` that you linked looks somewhat like an infinite stream of elements, which is again just a countably infinite data structure, not too dissimilar from a `List`. But I also can `filter` all kind of stuff that does *not* look like a `Foldable` data structure. For example, one can obviously filter sets intensionally defined by some condition `cond`: `class Set[X](cond: X => Boolean) { def contains(x: X) = cond(x) ; def filter(p: X => Boolean) = new Set[X](x => cond(x) && p(x)) }`. I don't see how such an intensional `Set[X]` can be made `Foldable`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I am not sure I understand this language _(Is it Scala? I only speak Haskell.)_, but would it be correct to say this definition is not constructive? In other words, it *implies* the presence of some type X and defines a predicate on it. If so, then X is the Foldable, and what we have her is _(isomorphic to)_ a filter.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Not sure what you mean by *constructive*. It's not extensional (no way to enumerate all the elements of a set, let alone `fold` over them in any meaningful way), but it's still *constructive* enough for [constructive solid geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry) for example, where we can wonderfully [`filter` all elements of a cube that are not contained in a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_solid_geometry#/media/File:Boolean_difference.PNG), without having to invoke any kind of `fold`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I mean that you do not offer a way to exhibit X yet — any of its points. So, you are not defining a _(Foldable)_ object, but merely a morphism from it. I do not know exactly how this picture is obtained, but my understanding of 3D graphics suggests that the filters that cut the sphere and the cube are symbolically linearly transformed to obtain a projection on a plane, and then the fold equipped with this projection is invoked on pixels, or some suitable abstraction thereof. Of course, it is anything but simple, but the more reason to look for a fold more scrupulously.

Answer (score 14):

One interesting way of looking at this matter involves not picking `filter` as a primitive notion. There is a Haskell type class called `Filterable` which [is aptly described as](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/witherable-0.2/docs/Data-Witherable.html):

> Like `Functor`, but it [includes] `Maybe` effects.
>
> Formally, the class `Filterable` represents a functor from **Kleisli Maybe** to **Hask**.

The morphism mapping of the "functor from `Kleisli Maybe` to **Hask**" is captured by the `mapMaybe` method of the class, which is indeed a generalisation of the homonymous `Data.Maybe` function:

```hs
mapMaybe :: Filterable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> f b
```

The class laws are simply the appropriate functor laws (note that `Just` and `(<=<)` are, respectively, identity and composition in **Kleisli Maybe**):

```hs
mapMaybe Just = id
mapMaybe (g <=< f) = mapMaybe g . mapMaybe f
```

The class can also be expressed in terms of `catMaybes`...

```hs
catMaybes :: Filterable f => f (Maybe a) -> f a
```

... which is interdefinable with `mapMaybe` (cf. the analogous relationship between `sequenceA` and `traverse`)...

```hs
catMaybes = mapMaybe id
mapMaybe g = catMaybes . fmap g
```

... and amounts to a natural transformation between the **Hask** endofunctors `Compose f Maybe` and `f`.

What does all of that have to do with your question? Firstly, a functor is a morphism between categories, and a natural transformation is a morphism between functors. That being so, it is possible to talk of morphisms here in a sense that is [less boring than the "morphisms in **Hask**" one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595873/2751851). You won't necessarily *want* to do so, but in any case it is an existing vantage point.

Secondly, `filter` is, unsurprisingly, also a method of `Filterable`, its default definition being:

```hs
filter :: Filterable f => (a -> Bool) -> f a -> f a
filter p = mapMaybe $ \a -> if p a then Just a else Nothing
```

Or, to spell it using [another cute combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49282010/2751851):

```hs
filter p = mapMaybe (ensure p)
```

That indirectly gives `filter` a place in this particular constellation of categorical notions.

Answer (score 12):

In this answer, I will assume that you are talking about `filter` on `Set` (the situation seems messier for other datatypes).

Let's first fix what we are talking about. I will talk specifically about the following function (in Scala):

```
def filter[A](p: A => Boolean): Set[A] => Set[A] = 
                                     s => s filter p
```

When we write it down this way, we see clearly that it's a polymorphic function with type parameter `A` that maps predicates `A => Boolean` to functions that map `Set[A]` to other `Set[A]`. To make it a "morphism", we would have to find some categories first, in which this thing could be a "morphism". One might hope that it's natural transformation, and therefore a morphism in the category of endofunctors on the "default ambient category-esque structure" usually referred to as "`Hask`" (or "`Scal`"? "`Scala`"?). To show that it's natural, we would have to check that the following diagram commutes for every `f: B => A`:

```
                       - o f
Hom[A, Boolean] ---------------------> Hom[B, Boolean]
     |                                       |
     |                                       |
     |                                       |
     | filter[A]                             | filter[B]
     |                                       |
     V                  ???                  V
Hom[Set[A], Set[A]] ---------------> Hom[Set[B], Set[B]]
```

however, here we fail immediately, because it's not clear what to even put on the horizontal arrow at the bottom, since the assignment `A -> Hom[Set[A], Set[A]]` doesn't even seem functorial (for the same reasons why `A -> End[A]` is not functorial, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854263/2707792) and also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21329/79922)).

The only "categorical" structure that I see here for a *fixed* type `A` is the following:

- Predicates on `A` can be considered to be a partially ordered set with implication, that is `p LEQ q` if `p` implies `q` (i.e. either `p(x)` must be false, or `q(x)` must be true for all `x: A`).
- Analogously, on functions `Set[A] => Set[A]`, we can define a partial order with `f LEQ g` whenever for each set `s: Set[A]` it holds that `f(s)` is subset of `g(s)`.

Then `filter[A]` would be monotonic, and therefore a functor between poset-categories. But that's somewhat boring.

Of course, for each fixed `A`, it (or rather its eta-expansion) is also just a function from `A => Boolean` to `Set[A] => Set[A]`, so it's automatically a "morphism" in the "`Hask`-category". But that's even more boring.

Comment: I meant `filter` on a collection. Or anything data structure actually. As long as `filter` accepts a predicate `p: A => Boolean` and must return a result of the same type. Depending on the condition of the predicate, the result could be empty, a subset or identical than the original data. I have edited the OP with an example.

Comment: TODO / Note for self: This whole thread is full of nonsense. 1) [`Sub(X) ~= Hom(X, \Omega)`](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subobject+classifier); 2) revisit the papers on "theorems for free", they're often using `filter` as example.

Answer (score 7):

`filter` can be written in terms of `foldRight` as:

```
filter p ys = foldRight(nil)( (x, xs) => if (p(x)) x::xs else xs ) ys
```

`foldRight` on lists is a map of T-algebras (where here T is the List datatype functor), so `filter` is a map of T-algebras.

The two algebras in question here are the initial list algebra

```
[nil, cons]: 1 + A x List(A) ----> List(A)
```

and, let's say the "filter" algebra,

```
[nil, f]: 1 + A x List(A) ----> List(A)
```

where `f(x, xs) = if p(x) x::xs else xs`.

Let's call `filter(p, _)` the unique map from the initial algebra to the filter algebra in this case (it is called `fold` in the general case). The fact that it is a map of algebras means that the following equations are satisfied:

```
filter(p, nil) = nil
filter(p, x::xs) = f(x, filter(p, xs))
```

Comment: On "I wanted to leave just a comment": this post stands well enough on its own as an answer, so don't worry about its length.

Comment: Also, generally speaking if something answers the question then it's better to have it as an answer. Comments are mostly for clarification/correction.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure I understand this answer. The arguments to `foldRight` look like a T-algebra to me, but the arguments to `filter` don't. How do I cram an arbitrary T-algebra into the type `a -> Bool`?

Comment: @iamcap7 Thanks for the answer. BTW, did you mean `x :: xs` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was mixing Scala and Haskell notation I think. @DanielWagner I added some more explanation in the hope that it makes it easy to understand.

Comment: `foldRight` is a map which takes T-algebras, but it doesn't (necessarily) produce T-algebras. And in particular the T-algebra that `filter` passes to `foldRight` does not produce a T-algebra, so `filter` itself is neither a T-algebra nor takes a T-algebra as an argument. There are several other factual mistakes in this post. Stripping them all away leaves almost no content beyond "`filter` can be defined in terms of `foldRight`" -- that is, just the first sentence.

Comment: foldRight, and so filter, is a map of T-algebras. It doesn’t produce T-algebras nor does it take T-algebras.

Comment: @iamcap7 What is a "map of T-algebras"? I can't reconcile any of the interpretations of "map" that I know of with "it doesn't produce T-algebras nor does it take T-algebras".

Comment: The most general case is as follows. Let `T : X ---> X` be a endofunctor, then a T-algebra is a map (morphism, arrow) `a : T(A) ---> A` in X. If `(A, a)` and `(B, b)` are T-algebras then a map (morphism) of these T-algebras is a map `f : A ---> B` such that `f a = b T(f)`.